# BeagleBone Black ide configuration on windows

Tags: ide, cross-compiling, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

i need a kickstart with beaglebone black on windows.

I' want to run my first helloworld on this device, using CodeComposer and Crosstool incoming with this.

I've the AngStrom default distro now, i can connect with ssh and running the gcc toolchain, 
I've compiled a simple helloworld, with nano and gcc on beagle.

But now i want to compile HelloWorld from windows IDE and next execute on the BBB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following two videos very informative in developing code on Windows for a BeagleBone Black target device:

- Derek Molloy has a series of videos on BeagleBone development, this one (second in a series) describes the cross-development process albeit from a Linux host: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFv_-ykLppo
- This video in particular was useful for me to get my Windows 7 x64 host using Eclipse (Kepler edition) working as an IDE for my BeagleBone Black project: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I667-sAzzZg

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio you can use VisualGDB plug in for it. It works for BBB and the Pi. 
No need for a VM, eclipse and all the steps involved.

However with the above VisualGDB plug in, compilation happens on the remote device so if you have a large project, it will take awhile to compile.